# Why does MS Access change the syntax of a query for no reason?

Tags: ms-access

I am building a utility for myself as I maintain a MS Access database with a large amount of VBA code and stored queries.

I exported the queries from two versions of the same database and my diff tool detected differences. I am sure I did not modify this query between version 1 and 2. Access seems to be silently modifying the syntax in a logically equivalent way somewhere along the line and I am looking for some help explaining this. When would Access do this, and why? I cannot recreate it at this time.

[image: Difference according to two versions of the same Access database]

Comment: Please review [ask] and [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 3):

Access attempts to parse all queries, and will adjust and standardize the SQL in multiple circumstances.

These include at least schema changes (table, query or field name changes) for dependent tables, and opening and saving the query in design view.

Your first query appears to have gone through this process. It usually involves addition of extraneous brackets and parentheses (quite limited in this case) and removal of newlines.

I have not seen this in instances where the schema of the database (both tables and queries) haven't changed and the query hasn't been opened in design view, but this might be triggered by other actions as well.