# How to prevent Access from removing square brackets around a column name in a querydef?

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, ms-access, sql-server-migration-assi

I want to convert an Access database to SQL Server. For this, I use SQL Server Migration Assistent.

One of the problems I encounter is that one of my columns is called `Current` and it's accessed in a query. I wrote a script that edits all querydefs and puts all column names in square brackets so that the edited version would be accepted by SQL Server.

I use this line in VBA to edit the SQL in the querydef:

```
CurrentDb.QueryDefs(queryName).SQL = newQuery
```

But it removes the square brackets. This causes SSMA to raise an error about the query, which results in the query not being migrated to a SQL Server view.

Is there any way I can prevent Access from removing the brackets when editing the SQL of the querydef?

The editing process works fine, for example when I give it this querydef:

```
SELECT [TableName].Current FROM [TableName];
```

it returns this:

```
SELECT [TableName].[Current] FROM [TableName];
```

But when I edit the query and open it in Design View, it removes all square brackets:

```
SELECT TableName.Current FROM TableName;
```

Also, when I manually edit the query, save&close, and reopen it, the square brackets are not removed (and I'm sure it was saved because other changes to the query are changed correctly). But manual editing is not something I want to do, because there are over 200 queries I need to edit.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/76175033/7296893, Access unfortunately does this often. There's no easy way to avoid this.

Comment: Perhaps you can rename the keyword column names before migration and rename them back afterwards.

Comment: Swallow the bitter pill, i.e: Rename columns that raise this type of error.